# What is AAFP socket on Motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

When I looking at my motherboard carefully, I can see a Socket named "`AAFP`".
Note: My motherboard is "`ASUS P5KPL SE`"
What is this socket and what does it do?

[image]

Comment: There are multiple hits via google that show it to be a front panel audio connection.

Comment: Have you looked at the manual for your mother board or as suggested, Google?

Comment: That is surprising, seeing as [googling](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=AAFP&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=AAFP+socket&safe=active) "AAFP socket" provides the first result as the answer.

Comment: If you guys had bothered to check his profile page, you’d have seen that he is in Iran which explains the lack of information both in his manual and his search results.

Comment: @synetech, I can't understand what is your mean. In my User-Manuel there is no explaining about the socket.

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri, I wasn’t talking to you, I was talking to the other people who complained that you did not bother checking your manual or Google. They found the information easily and thought that you should have as well, but if they had looked at your profile, they would see that you are in Iran, and that is why you cannot find the information easily.

Comment: @Synetech, Yes. here there are a lot of problems while your trying to get a help !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Googled 'ASUS P5KPL SE'. Got to the ASUS site (first hit). Then went to the downloads and got the manual. On page 1-32 of the manual:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [English manual](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5KPL_SE/#support_Download_30) shows the connector clearly.  Front Panel Audio Connector (10-1 Pin AAFP)